# auto adjust docked form width/height on a panel

Tags: delphi

In one of my application, there are 3 docking forms on a panel.

[image]

Everything is OK.
But when I adjust panel(the panel is on main form) size, it becomes

[image]

I hope to auto adjust width/height docked 3 forms to make them all display rather than hide some parts.

Comment: So? What is your question?

Comment: When I  adjust panel size, I hope to adjust the sizes of 3 docked form proportionally also

Comment: You don't need a splitter, all you need is to handle panel.OnResize and adjust 3 subpanels equally, as shown in the answer. So what was your question?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to adjust all the docking forms proportionally then it would probably be easiest to hook into the OnResize event of the Panel. Something like this:

```
procedure Panel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DockForm1.Width := Panel1.ClientWidth div 3;
  DockForm2.Width := DockForm1.Width;
  DockForm3.Width := Panel1.ClientWidth - (DockForm1.Width * 2);
end;
```

I am not sure what a docking form is but you may also need to set the positions of it.

Comment: if I adjust the splitter(where the red arrow is) or rearrange the 3 docked form on the panel, it will trigger which event? I can not find the event

Comment: @arachide The splitter has a OnMoved event. If you want to track percentages that are updated with the splitter then you should hook into that, save the percentage and then use those percentages when calculating the widths after the panel is resized.

Comment: but how to get the handler of the splitter? it is created by Delphi, I can not find where is its handler

Comment: @arachide Did you get sorted out or is your last comment still a problem for you?